# android studio retrieve data from firebase database on button click

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Can you please help to do this, I want to save some text in firebase, and display those text on button click. I don't want to put those text on my app, because I will make some change over time, and I don't want to send update every time. I have been look for a guide for a week now and tried a lot of code but no success.

Comment: Go through firebase docs. Your question is the basic example in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two storage options in Firebase.

1.Firebase Data Base
2.Firebase Storage

If you want to save data only, you can go with Firebase real time database.
If you want to store files like images..etc,you can go with Firebase Storage.
Both of them are real time database only.

since you mentioned that you want to store data

- To read and write from Firebase database data  [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) will help you.